# Does "expecting" mean "pregnant" exactly?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions, metaphors

The term *expecting* is often used as if it means "pregnant", as shown by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expecting) (for the verb *expect*)

> 3 : to be pregnant : await the birth of one's child —used in progressive tenses
>   she's expecting next month

and [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/expect) says

> informal Be pregnant.
>   ‘his wife was expecting again’

but logically you can only be *expecting* if you are *knowingly* pregnant and anticipating a successful conclusion.

There seem to be two issues here. One is how we should use terms that are metaphorical in origins in particular contexts where the original meaning seems to be the opposite of the derived meaning.

The other is whether we should go by the dictionary when we suspect the dictionary writers were not specific enough in their definition.

Note that this question was motivated by a [news report](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-manchester-47282950)  that said that surgeons "discovered that [Ebony, who did not previously know she was pregnant] was *expecting* a baby [while she was in a coma], and I thought, "How could she be expecting a baby or anything else whilst in a coma?"

Comment: I agree. “expecting” is a subset of “pregnant”.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction. You wouldn't use pregnant *either* unless the condition were known. I don't see anything about *expecting* that's the opposite of *pregnant*. Your news report example is somewhat misleading. She was still expecting—even though she didn't know it. The sense of the word is not the same as *anticipating*. (Or, if you want to say it is, then the hospital staff and her family were the ones doing the anticipating—in the same sense that couples can say ***we*** *are pregnant*.)

Comment: The reporter has simply used a common synonym for 'pregnant' without thinking.

Comment: That's right, @JasonBassford, she didn't use the term. Other people used the term referring to when she was in a coma. It often happens that the mother is not the first person to notice she is pregnant. If I think someone else is pregnant and she has not noticed anything, then, logically, *I am expecting* that she will have a baby, but *she* isn't. I think its meaning is similar to *anticipate*. MW gives this amongst a number of definitions other than the *pregnant* one and they almost all involve perception, such as *look forward*, *suppose*, *think*, *consider*.

Comment: That is the question, @KateBunting. Is it a mistake, or is it a valid use of the term? The reporter may have thought and decided it was OK, or they might not have thought - in which case we do not know if they would have changed it if they had thought.

Comment: @DavidRobinson You can ascribe a sense of awareness to the word if you like, but in common usage it is simply a synonym, and that extra sense isn't normally attached to it. (Although it may have been at one point in the past when it was first used in that way.) It's somewhat similar to associating the phrase *grin and bear it* with the animal, when in fact, even though the same word is used, it's used in a different sense. In the case of *expecting*, I've *only* used it to mean *pregnant* without any additional semantic freight.

Comment: In other words, in this context specifically, *expecting* is a medical condition, not a psychological state.

Comment: I think that may be a very important point, @JasonBassford. This is a medical context. The original quote was not *she was expecting*, but *[...] where medics discovered she was expecting*. So this is probably a quote from the medics. Now you mention it, I think *they* always use it referring to the medical condition (not considering what perception the woman may have), but I think its only use in a non-medical context may be when there is an actual anticipation (in the mind of the woman) of what is to occur.

Comment: Perhaps someone who has had a baby could answer the question of whether, looking back to the time between conception and diagnosis, they now consider that they were *expecting* then.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Well, Dr A says to Dr B:  “I have told her she is expecting, but she refuses to believe me and wants a second opinion. “. This is a correct use of the verb with a meaning we all accept.  The word ‘expecting’ has broken free from its root verb.  You can say “I hope I shall not expect again.”.  It has become almost a free adjective.  The verb ‘expect’ is transitive.  If I say “he is expecting.”, you say “Expecting what?” or , perhaps “I think you mean your partner is expecting”.   If I say “my partner is expecting” it can only mean one thing:  that SHE is PREGNANT.

Comment: You might as well argue that the etymology of pregnant is "before birth", so someone's pregnant all their life till they have a child. Etymological fantasy, anyone?

Comment: Obviously, the synonyms don't overlap in distribution completely. 1a ‘His wife was expecting again’ = 1b ‘His wife was pregnant again’. But 2a ‘His wife is expecting next month’ has no parallel.

Answer (score 2):

It’s a euphemism.
From the [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/pregnant#etymonline_v_19407) entry for "pregnant":

> The word tended to be avoided in polite conversation until c. 1950; modern euphemisms include anticipating, enceinte, expecting, in a family way, in a delicate (or interesting) condition. Old English terms included mid-bearne, literally "with child;" bearn-eaca, literally "child-adding" or "child-increasing;" and geacnod "increased." Among c. 1800 slang terms for "pregnant" was poisoned (in reference to the swelling).

The use of it always reminds me of a Lady Whiteadder (Blackadder's aunt) quote [source](http://www.comedyquotes.tv/blackadder-ii-episode-5-beer-script/)

> Aunt: [stands up] Don’t call me 'Aunty'!!! [slaps him twice]
>   `Aunt’ is a relative, and relatives are evidence of sex,
>   and sex is hardly a fitting subject for the dinner table. [sits]

It is a means of saying a baby is present but concealing the act of conception (because sex is "hardly a fitting subject" in polite company). Personally, I know where babies come from, so I’d take no issue with just saying "pregnant", but the contents of the news story you reference is already quite scandalous, so maybe the writer is simply attempting to tone it down for the more conservative amongst us.

Comment: Thank you, Pam. I realize it is a euphemism and I understand where the euphemism comes from and why  we use one in this context. It refers to all that is associated with looking forward to the 'happy event', which may involve celebration, thinking what you will call it, organizing maternity leave and many other things. My question is whether you can use it in a particular circumstance when the metaphor is clearly invalid - where Ebony had no expectation of anything and no opportunity to do any of the things associated with expecting a baby.

Answer (score 0):

I think "expecting" would fall under the category of being a polysemic word, which is a topic that has been discussed on StackExchange before:

[A word with a wide range of meanings](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65490/a-word-with-a-wide-range-of-meanings)

that doesn't address the logical aspects of the various meanings, but contronyms exist so it is perhaps not so far-fetched that a word like 'expecting' exists as it does in the English language.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I always thought we said that because we are expecting to have a baby at the end of this but miscarriages are so common that it might not end up this way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).