# Meaning of "expecting next month"?

Tags: word-usage

I read a definition of the word "expect" in Merriam Webster Dictionaries which was:

> to be pregnant : await the birth of one's child — used in progressive tenses- she's expecting next month

I want  to ask does the example sentence mean that "she" is going to get pregnant next month or going to give birth next month? Going by the definition I think the former should be right.

Comment: The very definition itself provides the answer. It says *await* ***the birth***, not *await* ***the pregnancy***.

Comment: Using "expecting" to mean "expecting to have sex" would be most inappropriate and comically silly for quite a variety of rather obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Expecting" refers to the expectation that she will be giving birth having already become pregnant.

Often times, you will hear couples use the term "trying" or other synonyms which generally refer to the other case you've pointed out -- attempting to become pregnant.

See this [similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/486137/does-expecting-mean-pregnant-exactly?rq=1)

Comment: Surely it's short for "expecting a baby"?