# Single word to mean 'having more than one meaning'

Tags: meaning

Is there a single word to mean the following:

'having more than one meanings'

Comment: [*Polysemous*](https://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/polysemous)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A word with a wide range of meanings](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65490/a-word-with-a-wide-range-of-meanings)

Comment: Also [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166916/name-of-words-with-multiple-meanings/166920#166920)

Answer (score 0):

The semantic phenomenon of words with multiple meanings is **polysemy**.

*Thoughtco* defines polysemy as follows:

> Polysemy is the association of one word with two or more distinct
>   meanings, and a polyseme is a word or phrase with multiple meanings.
>   The word "polysemy" comes from the Greek for "many signs." The
>   adjective forms of the word include polysemous or polysemic.

and states that "*According to some estimates, more than 40% of English words have more than one meaning.*"

The word *form* in the paragraph above is a polyseme with more than 24 senses in my Collins dictionary.

---

Reference: Polysemy - https://www.thoughtco.com/polysemy-words-and-meanings-1691642